# File version number in source with Vault

Tags: version-control, versioning

Is it possible to add Vault file version number into this file's source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$Revision: $` to specify the revision number in a comment of your source file.  You must enable Keyword Expansion for your repository by using the Admin Tool and changing Repository Options.  Check "Enable keyword expansion" in the keyword in the keyword expansion section and list file types, such as .txt, etc.

[Vault Q&A about turning on keyword expansion.](http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=5988)

[MSDN list of Keywords for VSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d826hy97(VS.80).aspx) (which are the same as used by Vault)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, there is a whole list of keywords that can be used in the Vault docs.
They can be found here http://download.sourcegear.com/misc/vault/help/admin/keywordexpansion.html